# Use variables for URI in WSDL mediators WSO2

Tags: wso2, wsdl, wso2-enterprise-integrator, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I am re-factorizing a wso2 project and I wondered how/whether I could do the following. This project is designed to send data to a **SOAP** Api. In every environment, this API exposes a `.wsdl` file and the URL and credentials are the only things changing from one environment to another. The most natural thing to do is thus to

- create those in the `Registry` and
- load it in the beginning of the job like so

```xml
<propertyGroup>
  <property expression="get-property('registry', 'gov:/endpoints/sap_constructionSiteUser')" name="sap_constructionSiteUser" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
  <property expression="get-property('registry', 'gov:/endpoints/sap_constructionSitePassword')" name="sap_constructionSitePassword" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
  <property expression="get-property('registry', 'gov:/endpoints/sap_constructionSiteUrl')" name="uri.var.sap_constructionSiteUrl" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
</propertyGroup>
```

But I could not find a **straightforward** way to use this `uri.var.sap_constructionSiteUrl` in the endpoint definition. The following does not work

```xml
<call>
  <endpoint>
     <wsdl optimize="mtom" uri="{uri.var.sap_constructionSiteUrl}" port="OUVERTURE_CHANTIER" service="OUVERTURE_CHANTIER" statistics="enable">
       <suspendOnFailure>
       <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
       <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
       <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
       </suspendOnFailure>
       <markForSuspension>
       <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
       </markForSuspension>
     </wsdl>
  </endpoint>
</call>
```

Looks like `uri=` only accept plain value. Is there a way I could made this dynamic without writing the entire endpoint in the `Registry` (the point is to keep things simple for the clients)

[**Environment**]

- wso2ei 6.5.0

====================**EDIT**========================

I just created a template:

```xml
<template name="crm4sap-constructionSiteTemplate" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <axis2ns488:parameter name="port" xmlns:axis2ns488="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"/>
    <axis2ns489:parameter name="service" xmlns:axis2ns489="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"/>
    <axis2ns490:parameter name="uri" xmlns:axis2ns490="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"/>
    <endpoint name="$name">
        <wsdl port="$port" service="$service" uri="$uri">
            <suspendOnFailure>
                <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
            </suspendOnFailure>
            <markForSuspension>
                <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
            </markForSuspension>
        </wsdl>
    </endpoint>
</template>
```

And I call it with

```xml
<call>
  <endpoint name="constructionSiteEndpoint" template="crm4sap-constructionSiteTemplate">
    <axis2ns468:parameter name="port" value="OUVERTURE_CHANTIER" xmlns:axis2ns468="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"/>
    <axis2ns469:parameter name="service" value="OUVERTURE_CHANTIER" xmlns:axis2ns469="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"/>
    <axis2ns469:parameter name="uri" value="{$ctx:sap_constructionSiteUrl}" xmlns:axis2ns469="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"/>
  </endpoint>
</call>
```

Variable substitution does not seem to occur:

```sh
[2020-04-15 12:30:54,032] []  WARN - TemplateEndpointFactory Could not read the WSDL endpoint {$ctx:sap_constructionSiteUrl}
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: {$ctx:sap_constructionSiteUrl}
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:600)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:497)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:446)
```

Looks like a [common problem](http://wso2-oxygen-tank.10903.n7.nabble.com/Manage-ESB-Endpoint-configs-dynamically-td131023.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to template this endpoint and then call the template with the parameters. You can pass dynamic values to the template in the runtime.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Endpoint+Template

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it using the following code in the sequence:

```
 <call-template target="template-for-calling-soap">
        <with-param name="url" value="{get-property('soap-uri')}"/>
 </call-template>
```

Where soap-uri is a local entry or a simple property, and the sequence template named template-for-calling-soap takes as parameter the url value and has the following code:

```
<template name="template-for-calling-soap" 
xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameter name="url"/>
    <sequence>
       <property expression="$func:url" name="uri.var" scope="default" 
        type="STRING"/>
       <send>
            <endpoint>
                <address format="soap11" uri="${uri.var}"/>
            </endpoint>
       </send>
    </sequence>
</template>
```